# Query a table with 100M rows

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have 103216342 rows in a table with 4 columns in a MySQL database. When I am querying it, it will just hang. Even a normal select query is not executed. What do I have to do with this table so that I am able to perform queries on it?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dealerzipcoderanges` (
  `DealerZipCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `FromZipCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `ZipCodeName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Miles` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DealerZipCode`,`FromZipCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have three tables, `Inventories` ,`Dealerships`, and `dealerzipcoderanges`. Two of them are properly indexed (with `primary key int`). I am getting records from joining all three tables. Joining two (`Inventories` and `Dealerships`) worked properly, but when I joined the `dealerzipcoderanges` table, I have problems. It's buffered for infinite time and respond nothing.

`Inventories` is almost 1.5GB, `Dealerships` is 200 MB, and `dealerzipcoderanges` (with `primary key varchar`) is 4.3GB.

Users query with `zipcodes` for `Inventories` with a distance in miles between zipcodes. We have to map dealer's `zipcode` and user's `zipcode` to map the proper distance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM inventories 
  INNER JOIN dealerships 
    ON inventories.DealershipId = dealerships.DealershipId 
  INNER JOIN dealerzipcoderanges 
    ON dealerships.ZIP = dealerzipcoderanges.DealerZipCode 
WHERE dealerzipcoderanges.Miles = '100' 
  AND dealerzipcoderanges.FromZipCode = '12345';
```

#### Inventories

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventories` (
  `InventoryId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DealershipId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateInserted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DateRemoved` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RemovedBy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VIN` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Stock` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Make` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModelNumber` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Body` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StandardBody` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trim` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Miles` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CarFaxReportURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CarFaxOneOwner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` longtext,
  `EPACity` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EPAHighway` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExtColor` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IntColor` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellingPrice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VideoURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PhotoURL` longtext,
  `ImageModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageLastImportDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RemoveFlag` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=''Active'' , 0=''Move To Trash''',
  `StatusChangeDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ImportMethodTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`InventoryId`),
  KEY `IX_Inventory_DealershipId` (`DealershipId`),
  KEY `IX_Inventory_SearchFields` (`Make`),
  KEY `IX_Inventory_VIN` (`VIN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=881752 ;
```

#### Dealerships

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Dealerships` (
  `DealershipId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DealerGroupId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventoryProviderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dealership` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrackingNumber` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AuthorizedDealerName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RepresentativeEmail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WebsiteURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hours` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` longtext,
  `Services` longtext,
  `Address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIP` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatitudeLongitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventoryAuthorize` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SalesPersonId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Manufacturer` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ManufacturerParentId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateActivated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ActivateReason` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateCanceled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ManufacturerImport` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ManufacturerDealerCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DealershipId`),
  KEY `IX_Dealerships_DateActivated` (`DateActivated`),
  KEY `IX_Dealerships_State` (`State`),
  KEY `IX_Dealerships_ZIP` (`ZIP`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 3):

For

```
AND dealerzipcoderanges.FromZipCode = '12345';
```

it would be much better to have

```
PRIMARY KEY (`FromZipCode`, `DealerZipCode`)
```

Still better would be to *also* have

```
INDEX(FromZipCode, Miles)
```

If you really mean `WHERE Miles < 100`.

What you currently have cannot use *any* index on your 100M-row table, so it *will* "hang forever".  With the indexes above, it will run a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would add index on `inventories.DealershipId` and `dealerships.ZIP`. Hard to say what is happening without EXPLAIN plan.
I would be also sceptic about adding indexes on double data type columns.